# Erro de conexão Node e MySQL no Docker Compose: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

Criei um arquivo `docker-compose.yml` para carregar um banco de dados MySQL e um servidor NodeJS:

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: 'database'
    restart: 'always'
    volumes:
      - ./src/database/data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'data-mysql'
  api:
    image: node:10.16-slim
    container_name: 'api'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    working_dir: '/home/node/app'
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    command: 'yarn server'
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: 'bridge'
```

No meu terminal, quando dou o comando: `docker-compose up -d`, aparece:

```
Creating network "backend_backend" with driver "bridge"
Creating node-api ... 
Creating my-database ... 
Creating my-database
Creating my-database ... done
```

Vendo os contêineres ativos, com o comando `docker ps`, aparece:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
fca4c78e70c5        node:10.16-slim     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp              node-api
f9702dbec8c5        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   my-database
```

Após tudo isso, quando vou ver os logs do contêiner `node-api`, com o comando `docker logs -f fca4c78e70c5`, aparece:

```
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/server.ts src/server.ts`
(node:41) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/node/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/node/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/home/node/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js
```

Estou fazendo um projeto com TypeORM, uma ORM do TypeScript, o arquivo de configuração e conexão com o banco de dados é:

```
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "root",
  "password": "root",
  "database": "data-mysql",
  "logging": true,
  "entities": [
    "src/models/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "src/database/migrations/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/models",
    "migrationsDir": "src/database/migrations"
  }
}
```

Já pesquisei bastante e não encontrei nada que resolvesse esse problema, alguém pode me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço todas as respostas! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Fala galera! Seguinte, ninguém me respondeu.**

Então, como todo bom e velho programador, fui pesquisar **mais** para encontrar a solução desse meu problema, e sim, eu achei a resposta.

O que estava acontecendo era que no meu arquivo *ormconfig.json* eu estava setando o *host* do meu banco da dados como *localhost*, quando na verdade eu deveria setar como o contêiner que eu criei no **Docker Compose**, que nesse caso é *database*.

Alterando o arquivo, ficou assim:

```js
{
  "type": "mysql",
  "host": "database",
  "port": 3306,
  "username": "root",
  "password": "root",
  "database": "data-mysql",
  "logging": true,
  "entities": [
    "src/models/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "src/database/migrations/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/models",
    "migrationsDir": "src/database/migrations"
  }
}
```

Então para rodar os contêineres, é só rodar o comando:

```bsh
docker-compose up -d
```

**Espero ajudar mais alguém que esteja com o mesmo problema!**